# Class not found in Google Endpoint [Java]

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

How classes are included in Google Endpoint API is not clear to me.
I properly register classes in ofy, like this

```
ObjectifyService.register(Thing.class);
ObjectifyService.register(AnotherThing.class);
```

and it all seem to work when using api explorer.

But when it comes to using this classes on the client some classes are not imported in my api-v1-java.zip. How can I add them?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that a new class "appears" in the api-v1-java.zip when I return it in an `@ApiMethod`. I still don't understand when or after which event they appear, since they are not present as soon as I return those objects or test the method in the api explorer, but some time later. Any more specific answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you generate a client library using Google's libraries, it generates a surface that has no code dependency on your API. The model it uses is a completely separate set of classes. They tend to have similar names and properties, though.

Comment: So do you suggest creating my own class, ignoring the classes generated by the api?

Comment: For the client, use the generated classes. For the server, use the classes you wrote.

Comment: The problem is that I don't understand how to generate client classes. The only way I found, as stated in another answer, is declaring them as return type for a @ApiMethod. I don't return all the types, so some are missing in the client library

Comment: If a type is not transitively used in a request or response, then it will not have a corresponding model class in the generated client library, because it's not part of the API surface.

Comment: Ok, so the only way to export a class is to expose it in a request or response. Thank you!